# ASP.NET Cache concurrency

Tags: asp.net, caching

Quick question about using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache in ASP.NET. Is it concurrency safe? By this I mean that if I do something like this:

```
Cache.Insert("user", user, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), TimeSpan.Zero)
```

then the cache called 'user' is unique to each and every user of the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET cache is shared over the users. You should use the session to store user specific items.